# Optimise a simple double for loop for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, optimization

```
array.sort(function(left, right) {
    return index(otherArray, left) < index(otherArray, right);
});
```

This is `O(len(array) ^ 2)` so for a reasonable size array of len = 1000 this takes constant * 1 million operations which easily overshoots the IE 5 million operators cap.

Thus IE throws a script is taking too long even though this is fast.

The problem is that IE does not have it's own `Array.prototype.indexOf` so I can't reduce the operation count down to `O(len(array)` and rely instead end up using a double for loop instead of a single for loop.

I considered array.join and using String.prototype.indexOf but the objects in the arrays are DOM elements and you can't convert them to a string (easily).

Telling IE users to remove this default cap is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions to this problem: one of which will work everywhere, the other which is entirely IE-proprietary (and I expect doesn't work in IE9, but that supports `Array.prototype.indexOf`, so that's a non-issue).

The first, simpler, solution is to just set a property on each HTMLElement of the desired order and sort by that. If you care about the desired order persisting, you'll have to make sure the HTMLElement objects don't get garbage collected, so you'll have to keep references to them around (it's probably simplest to just create an array in the global scope for it).

The IE-only solution is to do something similar to what @maclema was proposing, using a lookup object, and `HTMLElement.uniqueID`:

```
var otherArrayLookup = {};
for (var i=0; i < otherArray.length; i++) {
    otherArrayLookup[otherArray[i].uniqueID] = i;
}

array.sort(function(left, right) {
    return otherArrayLookup[left.uniqueID] < otherArrayLookup[right.uniqueID];
});
```

You'll want to add some branches in there (don't put any within the callback function, but use different callback functions) for the `Array.prototype.indexOf` supported case, the `HTMLElement.uniqueID` supported case, and the none-of-the-above case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making an index lookup object. This should greatly increase performance too.

```
var otherArrayLookup = {};
for ( var i=0; i<otherArray.length; i++ ) {
    otherArrayLookup[otherArray[i]] = i;
}

array.sort(function(left, right) {
    return otherArrayLookup[left] < otherArrayLookup[right];
});
```

Comment: But that won't actually work — look at what otherArrayLookup becomes: it'll be something like `{"[object HTMLBodyElement]": 1, "[object HTMLHeaderElement]": 2}` even when there were far more elements in otherArray.

Comment: More like O(n log n).  But still better than O(n^2)

Comment: @gsnedders has a good point. It doesn't work, It would require a unique id for each row.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, it won't work. I was actually thinking of Actionscript.